# What is the technical term for when a URL is repeated within the same URL?

Tags: url, scene7

I have an API that returns URL that render an image from Adobe Scene7. The API is doubling up, or repeating, the URL in the XML return and is causing parsing issues in my presentation. Is there a technical term for this repeated URL? I need to know how to report this to my developers.

Here is an example, in the URL can see where the protocol starts and repeats the exact same URL...

```
<d1p1:ProductImageUrl>http://s7d7.scene7.com/is/image/BBE004?&op_colorize=0f5196http://s7d7.scene7.com/is/image/BBE004?&op_colorize=0f5196</d1p1:ProductImageUrl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the technical term for this is "invalid URL".

Comment: I agree, I would report it as an invalid URL and provide the exact string so they can see what the unexpected result is

Comment: that works. just didn't know if there was some term for it that i wasn't finding in a google search.